# group by rolling slow on one instance but faster on another, is it possible to optimize

Tags: pandas

I wanted to perform group by rolling sum, but I see quite different performance in two types of cases. Consider this two case:

Case 1, "time" and "id" has roughly the same size of 3000.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size_now = 1e6

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":np.random.randint(3000,size=int(size_now)),
             "id":np.random.randint(3000,size=int(size_now)),
             "data":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now))})

df.time =  pd.to_datetime(df.time,unit="s")

df = df.groupby(["id","time"]).sum().reset_index()
```

then

```
%time df.sort_values(["id","time"]).groupby("id").rolling("1001ms",on="time")[["data"]].sum().sort_index()

executed in 692ms, finished 10:25:20 2021-07-20
CPU times: user 568 ms, sys: 41.6 ms, total: 610 ms
Wall time: 671 ms
```

It took 700ms to complete the calculations.

Case 2, where `id` varies significantly more than `time`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size_now = 1e6

df = pd.DataFrame({"time":np.random.randint(162,size=int(size_now)),
             "id":np.random.randint(70000,size=int(size_now)),
             "data":np.random.randint(1000,size=int(size_now))})

df.time =  pd.to_datetime(df.time,unit="s")

df = df.groupby(["id","time"]).sum().reset_index()
```

Then

```
%time df.sort_values(["id","time"]).groupby("id").rolling("1001ms",on="time")[["data"]].sum().sort_index()

executed in 2.90s, finished 10:28:39 2021-07-20
CPU times: user 2.84 s, sys: 45.7 ms, total: 2.89 s
Wall time: 2.88 s
```

speed is much slower now... is it possible to optimize Case 2 to have similar performance as Case 1?